# Break line in printdocument in C# winform

Tags: c#, printdocument

I'm trying to make a customer certification using PrintDocuments, i simply want if the text Character greater then 19 it break the line and printer the renaming text in Next line.
Thanks in advance

```
My code : 


if (Fotertex.ToString().Length > 19)
          {
              graphics.DrawString(Fotertex.Text, myfont, Brushes.Black, new PointF(10,40));
          }
```

Comment: There are no "lines", it is up to you to increment the PointF argument by the font height.

Comment: And, what do you mean by _"if the text Character greater then 19"_?  All printable characters are greater than 19 (the first printable character is a space, `0x20`)

Comment: @HansPassant can you please explain more can you tell me how i can increment the pointF 
Thank you

Comment: Hello everyone i find a solution :

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that it works for me, it helps to break line in the printed document.

The code is :

```
       private void printDocument3_PrintPage(object sender,  System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

        int yMargin;
        Font myFont = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
        yMargin = e.MarginBounds.Y;
        // Create rectangle for drawing. 
        float x = 150;
        float y = 180;
        float width =530;
        float height = 1000;
        RectangleF drawRect = new RectangleF(x, y, width, height);

        e.Graphics.DrawString(test4.Text, myFont, Brushes.Black, drawRect);


    }
```

Hope it will help if some one need ;)